# Lisp, sub total of a numbers in a nested list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

i have a problem that i just cant work out,

the user enters a list ie

```
 (total-cost 
   '((anItem 2 0.01) 
     (item 3 0.10) 
     (anotherItem 4 4.10) 
     (item 5 2.51)))
```

i need to add the number on the end together and then return the result

my current code returns the code after each addition. and also throws a error about unexpected type

```
(defun total-cost (list)
  (loop with sum = 0
        for x in list
      collect (setf sum (+ sum (last x)))
   )
)
```

Error: `(0.01)' is not of the expected type`NUMBER'

Any help is appreciated
Thanks Dale

Answer (score 10):

Using `LOOP`:

```
CL-USER 19 > (loop for (nil nil number) in '((anItem      2 0.01) 
                                             (item        3 0.10) 
                                             (anotherItem 4 4.10) 
                                             (item        5 2.51))
                   sum number)
6.72
```

`REDUCE` is another option:

```
CL-USER 20 > (reduce '+
                     '((anItem      2 0.01) 
                       (item        3 0.10) 
                       (anotherItem 4 4.10) 
                       (item        5 2.51))
                     :key 'third)
6.72
```

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: Ha! Why are you so excited?

Comment: Because it's an awesome, elegant solution. Especially the destructuring one. Unfortunately, destructuring isn't that commonly used in the Scheme world (it's used in the `match` macro, but that's about it), so it's not the first solution I reach for, much of the time, and I need to learn to use it more frequently.

Answer (score 5):

Loop has a keyword `sum` for summing so you don't have to have an explicit variable nor use `setf`:

```
(defun total-cost (list)
  (loop for x in list sum (third x)))
```

As Chris said, use `(car (last x))` if the number you're looking for is always the last one. Or you can use `(third x)` as in my example if it's always the third one.

Also, note that the use of `collect`is wrong if your aim is to return the sum only; your example (corrected) returns

```
(0.01 0.11 4.21 6.7200003)
```

whereas mine returns

```
6.7200003
```

Note that if you want so escape the rounding errors as much as possible you need to use an [exponent marker](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_e.htm#exponent_marker) to make them double-floats for example:

```
(total-cost '((anItem 2 0.01D0)
             (item 3 0.10D0) 
             (anotherItem 4 4.10D0) 
             (item 5 2.51D0)))
=> 6.72D0
```

Comment: also see `*READ-DEFAULT-FLOAT-FORMAT*`

Comment: If you are at the topic of money, _do not use floating point numbers_!

Comment: @Svante Certainly. I would use integers for that (representing cents).

Answer (score 3):

`last` returns the last cons cell in the list, not its value. You need to use `(car (last x))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you want the code to give you a precise result rather then being short:

```
(defun kahan-sum (floats)
  (loop
     :with sum := 0.0 :and error := 0.0
     :for float :in floats
     :for epsilon := (- float error)
     :for corrected-sum := (+ sum epsilon) :do
     (setf error (- corrected-sum sum epsilon) sum corrected-sum)
     :finally (return sum)))

(defun naive-sum (floats) (loop :for float :in floats :sum float))

(let ((floats (loop :repeat 1000 :collect (- (random 1000000.0) 1000000.0))))
  (format t "~&naive sum: ~f, kahan sum: ~f" (naive-sum floats) (kahan-sum floats)))
;; naive sum: -498127420.0, kahan sum: -498127600.0
```

Read more about why it works like this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Coming late to the party...  How about a little lisping instead of `loop`ing?   ;-)

```
(defun sum-3rd (xs)
  (let ((sum 0))
    (dolist (x xs sum) 
      (incf sum (nth 2 x)))))
```